# deep linking with expo to a specific screen or component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, expo

Hello I’m using the exact code from https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linking and I’m unable to specify any path into my app besides the root component. When I send a path to specific screen like `Linking.makeUrl(‘screens/coolscreen’, { hello: ‘world’, goodbye: ‘now’ })`, I get something like this `exp://localhost:19000/--/screens/coolscreen`. What is this -- being added? I can’t find any helpful examples online at all. Any tips are appreciated.

I've also tried adding a 'path' to each screen on the main navigator and specifying that path like `Linking.makeUrl('tabs', { hello: ‘world’, goodbye: ‘now’ })`. Still nothing .